# SQL Server remote calls extremely slow on Windows 8.1

Tags: c#, sql-server, windows-8.1

We recently upgraded a few of our workstations from Windows 8 to Windows 8.1 and one of our Windows Forms applications written in C# went from taking 3-4 seconds to open to 3-4 minutes to open. This application makes many SQL calls directly to a server on the LAN running SQL Server 2008.

I profiled the application and the bottlenecks (99% CPU time) are calls to `DbDataAdapter.Fill()` and `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()`.

What steps should I take to regain sane performance for remote SQL calls in Windows 8.1?

Comment: First establish which queries are slower and make sure you measure them in the same way (SQL Server & client both cold (restarted)), and then make a comparison with the lower version of windows. Also ensure that that same versions of the SQL Client software is used on both. You need to establish exactly what is slow and under what conditions.

Comment: @PreetSangha I'm not sure what you mean by "SQL Client software". The client is the .NET framework, identical on all systems. Every query is **minutes** slower. This is a general remote SQL latency problem directly related to Windows 8.1.

Comment: Run SQL Profiler on the database server with the 8 and 8.1 connections see if there is a difference in what is executed.

Comment: @SqlACID Why would there be? That would mean Windows 8.1 is intercepting my calls and modifying the command text since neither the server nor the client has changed.

Comment: So you should be able to reproduce it using a simple select from a simple table? The SQL Client is what needs to be installed on any workstation before you can make a call to SQL Server. What I'm saying is once you've determined that actual changes between the systems then you can get down to debugging. At this point your question is two broad to answer as you've not specified enough information to debug it.

Comment: @PreetSangha Can you please define "SQL Client"? Preferably with a link to whatever you're referring to. I never installed any such thing.

Comment: I can't recall off the top of my head - it used to be called MDAC and often is preinstalled in windows. What I'm thinking is that you should be able to eliminate this as a variable if you use set the same versions on both systems. The other thing that the profiler can tell you is how long negotiations for things such as opening connections is taking. Your issue might be related to that rather than query time. This is why I suggest isolation first.

Comment: @PreetSangha Is that not ruled out by the fact that the calls taking up 99% of the time are `Fill` and `ExecuteReader` (as opposed to `Open`)?